# How to pass parameter to with_api_auth(access_id, secret_key) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api-auth

I created one class to call api on other rails server.

### Client (RemoteAssessment.rb):

class RemoteAssessment < ActiveResource::Base

```
self.site = "http://localhost:5000/api/v1"

headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

with_api_auth(access_id, secret_key)
```

end

### Calling code (onefile.rb):

RemoteAssessment.find('4')

I want to pass "access_id" and "secret_key" from my caller (onefile.rb). I tried multiple ways but it is not working.

I am new to ruby on rails, so it may be a basic question.

Please help me to figure out passing parameter from caller.

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is

```
Client (RemoteAssessment.rb):

class RemoteAssessment < ActiveResource::Base

  def self.with_api_auth(access_id, secret_key)

  end
end
```

and in

```
remoteAssessment = RemoteAssessment.find('4')

remoteAssessment.with_api_auth(ENV['access_id'], ENV['secret_key']
```

and other you can create service class and pass `access_id` and `secret_key`

Comment: Thanks Bhupati.

I tried your solution but it is not working. As api is calling before in your solution and after that it is calling the with_api_auth.

Also these parameter will be different for each login, we can not take it from ENV variables.

Comment: could you show some more code from where you are calling this or may be github link so that it will be easier to debug